# Shorten command line in IntelliJ is not working

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build

I have a gradle project which I want to build on Windows.

I got an error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 'xxx'.
A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe''

BUILD FAILED in 23s
25 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 24 up-to-date
CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long.
```

So, as serveral people wrote here, I was looking for *shorten command line* option. I found this option in *Run/Debug Configuration* but not available for Gradle settings, I found it in, for example, JUnit options.

I also tried to add

```
<component name="PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="dynamic.classpath" value="true" />
</component>
```

in .idea/workspace.xml,unfortunately, it didn't help either.

Has anyone already solved this problem?

Comment: Please check these issues: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178417
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187071.

Comment: ok, so I added this solution to my build.gradle file. It is still not working. :<